# Inclusion relationship between $\mathscr l^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

In Folland’s Real Analysis book, we have the following proposition:

“ If $\mu(X)< \infty$ and $0<p<q\le \infty$, then $L^p(\mu)\supset L^q(\mu)$.”

So suppose that $A$ is a finite set and $\mu$ is the counting measure on $A$. If $0<p<q\le\infty$, does it follow that $\mathscr l^p(A)\supset \mathscr l^q(A)$? I am asking this question because usually I see the reverse inclusion for $\mathscr l^p$ spaces.

Comment: If $A=\Bbb N$, then the reverse inclusion is right. But if $A$ is finite, all $l^p$ spaces are the same since finite sum always converges.

Comment: thanks I got it @Song

Comment: Folland Problem 6.5 I believe characterizes the inclusions of $L^p$ spaces when only one measure is involved, and for the inclusion $L^p(\mu) \subset L^q(\nu)$, Folland references a paper in the Notes and Remarks section of chapter 6.